How to display columns when there are no data in the pivot table using AG Grid?
Using AG Grid React, I have a pivot table for orders that looks like this:



Group
2010-09-01
2010-09-05
2010-09-20





sum(num_of_packages)
sum(num_of_packages)
sum(num_of_packages)


Japan
1
2
3


USA
10
20
30


Brazil
2
2
4




This table has pivotMode: true
shipped_at has pivot: true
location has row_group: true
num_of_packages has aggFunc: 'sum'

In short, it is grouping orders by shipped_at. On 2010-09-01, there were 1 package headed to Japan, 10 to USA, and 2 to Brazil. On 2010-09-05, there were 2 packages headed to Japan, 20 to USA, and 2 to Brazil, etc.
What I'm trying to do is, I want to display all days as columns for the month of September 2010. Any shipments that weren't recorded would display 0. I want it to look something like this:



Group
2010-09-01
2010-09-02
2010-09-03
2010-09-04
2010-09-05
etc (all the way to 2010-09-30)





sum(num_of_packages)
sum(num_of_packages)
sum(num_of_packages)
sum(num_of_packages)
sum(num_of_packages)
sum(num_of_packages)


Japan
1
0
0
0
2
...etc


USA
10
0
0
0
20
...etc


Brazil
2
0
0
0
2
...etc



How can I create additional colGroupDefs for every day in the month that display a default value of 0 if there are no data for those dates?
I've looked at the pages related to Pivoting, aggregations custom functions, and other API page (I'm using ag-grid-react + enterprise v31.3.2), but didn't find anything for my use case.

create a function that adds the missing dates for each location with num_of_packages set to 0 for each additional date you need. Amend you rowData.
